# Cursor blinks and no copy paste works in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, vlc-media-player, netbeans

From few days i'm experiencing weird issue with my system. My cursor keeps on blinking and copy paste doesn't works. I copy and when i go to paste, i find paste option is disable. Interesting thing is i can toggle this behavior with numlock, as i press numlock it stops blinking and copy paste works, but after sometime same behavior occurs. I guess that cursor blink is because of something continuously emptying my clip board, but what it could be? I haven't install anything new recently. Mostly I only keep open Firefox (checked for addons, nothing new or suspicious), vlc and netbeans open. Any guesses?

Comment: aren't you admin user of your os?at which account you are facing this issue?

Comment: yes an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the Skype "click to call" add-in in IE and Firefox and the copy/paste functions should return to normal when IE and/or Firefox are running. It looks like some sort of Skype-Office-browsers memory-management issues